# How should I tip if the food is good but the service from the waiter/waitress is terrible in the USA?

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, tipping

I tip all the time in the USA, usually from 15% up to 20%. The food is usually good but sometimes the service I received from the waiter/waitress is terrible. He/She was basically ignore me all the time, even though I made multiple requests.

Should I reduce the amount of tip, or leave a message on the receipt to let him/her know if he/she is terrible? What if the food is *really* good?

Comment: I never tip, the waiter is supposed to do his/her job and the employer is supposed to pay the employee, taking work performance into account if necessary. I don't see why the employer should outsource part of his/her duties to the customer.

Comment: @CountIblis If you're in the US, that's simply wrong.  The cultural expectation is that you tip around 15% on average for restaurant service, and that's made it into the system directly.  Waiters are typically paid $2-$3 an hour.  You can disagree with the cultural mechanism all you want, but not tipping the waitstaff nonetheless is just rude.

Comment: @Joe and then people are surprised when they got a bad service. If you must pay a tip, no matter how crappy the service was, why should a waiter bother to provide you with any service at all. Just wait for "cultural expectation" and do nothing.

Comment: The waiter should provide you with service or else he will be fired, same as anything else.  Why should the software developer do any work?  In any event, the reason for my comment was the one above it, which was not addressing quality of service at all.

Comment: But how should he be fired if there is 0 feedback? He did a crappy job - got 15%, did a normal job - got 15%. How should he or his manager can find out that he underperforms? On the other hand there is no cultural expectation in software development. If I missed a few deadlines and wait for a cultural expectation to bring me a promotion, my manager will notice it and will fire me.

Comment: @SalvadorDali You tip accordingly. I've left 2c tips before when a waitress was too busy gossiping to get us something as simple as water. If you get bad service, tipping low IS THE WAY you put forth that across... and maybe a note on the receipt. Or a complaint to management as well as no tip. You don't HAVE to tip 15%... that's what's expected for except able service... Go up or down depending on what service you actually receive. It's not a hard concept.

Comment: "My compliments to the chef." Nice restaurants (as in those that actually have a chef) will be glad to arrange a brief introduction to the chef after your dinner, so you can deliver your "compliments" directly.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Tipping is for the service, the menu price is for the food.

If the service is bad, leave a small tip.  This will show the wait person that you didn't forget to tip, but felt that their service was undeserving.

On the converse, it is important not to leave a poor tip if the food was bad but the service was good.  The wait staff can not make the food better and should not be punished for that.  If this is the case, I would probably not go back to the restaurant again.  I can get a better/different waitperson next time, but the number of chefs is much more limited.

Comment: Ins't the tip a % between 15 and 20? Can you actually leave less money if you feel the service is bad? Or you leave the least within the range?

Comment: Tip is whatever amount you want to leave.  A range of 15-20 is reasonable starting point.  There is no requirement that you tip (although there is an expectation) and certainly if you want to send a message, leaving less than 15% could do that.  Of course, some waitpersons do not recognize their own shortcomings, and will think you are just cheap.  YMMV.

Comment: @nsn The smallest tip is actually $0.01 - in US custom this is the most extreme criticism of a waitperson, and is akin to directly saying "I left this penny just to let you know I didn't forget to leave a tip - you really treated us that terribly" - it's not far from "screw you". Out of easily thousands of visits to restaurants in my lifetime in the US I've maybe had reason to do this...once, twice maybe? <15% of a bill is considered a somewhat low tip, with 15% meaning "you were adequate" and 20%+ being "you did a great job, I'm leaving you more than social custom requires".

Comment: @nsn it's not like there's a law. you never *have* to tip for anything, under any circumstance. but everyone does, because that's how the culture works. 15-20% is just an unwritten rule that everyone has agreed on.

Comment: Thanks for the cultural tips :) - I thoought it was more than just cultural phenomen since I heard some restaurant invoices even specify the tip you have to give.

Comment: @nsn restaurants are allowed to require tipping ("gratuity"). that's their right as a business. this is a common thing, but usually restaurants only force you to pay gratuity when there's a certain minimum number of diners (5-7, typically). i've never heard of a restaurant that requires gratuity on *all* meals.

Comment: @BrianDHall $0.02, not $0.01 — just my two cents :)

Comment: It is perhaps worth nothing that some places are more expensive than others: 15% is a kind of poor tip in New York City, for instance (traditionally the typical tip is twice the tax, or 17.75%, but simply 20% for typical service is becoming more common).

Comment: I usually tip 20%, largely because I've known a lot of people who worked as waiters coming up who have related just how many people don't tip at all, ever. In the USA a 15% tip is customary, but some people just tip $5 no matter how big the check is; some tip 10% because it's easy to calculate; and some don't tip at all because they're cheap. I tip 20% - and usually have the wait-staff fighting to get me in their section. I've been known to tip more than the check if it's a small check (e.g. ice cream with my young daughter) and the waitress made the visit fun/special (e.g. 10$ on a 5$ check).

Comment: Ahh... it's a bit like buying a movie-DVD then - I can buy the DVD, but that doesn't mean I've bought the right to actually *play* it (zones, "copy" protection, ...)?  I can buy the food, but can't simultaneously expect that anybody will bother to bring the food to my table!  Wacky world...

Comment: If the food is bad, talk to management. They will usually make it right rather than face embarrassment from publicity. Most managers actually care about what their customers think, too. The customary response is a refund for your meal and/or a replacement on the spot. However, don't leave a poor tip just because of the food. And yes, tipped employees make up to 75% less than salary/hourly employees. They literally depend on those tips for their next meal. I've had that job before. Most waiters/waitresses are genuinely nice, if not stressed, but are victims of circumstance. Tip well.

Answer (score 30):

cdkMoose is correct in that the quality of the food should not influence your tip. However, your question appears to operate on a bit of a false premise, and I think it should also be said that **leaving a small tip for poor service should be done only in exceptional circumstances.**

By exceptional circumstances, I mean active hostilty or extreme rudeness on the part of the waiter. In a case where the waiter is simply inattentive, you should still leave a full tip. Here's why:

- At many restaurants and especially during peak hours, waiters are severely overworked, and often cannot be as attentive as they might like.
- Wait staff at most restaurants in the US are paid almost completely out of tips. Getting a tip isn't a nice little bonus for good service, it's their livelihood.
- Few other professions demand such constant attentiveness with the possibility of immediate financial penalty for a single failure. If I'm having a slow day at work, my boss might reprimand me, but can't arbitrarily cut my next paycheck.
- Tipping culture is strongly ingrained in the US, and many will see leaving a small tip as extremely rude, even if service was suboptimal.

If you want to tip based on quality of service, I would suggest adopting the opposite mentality to the one espoused in your question; rather than punishing poor service, reward good service. For instance, plan always to tip 20% as a fixed 'service fee', but occasionally leave an additional 5-10% 'voluntary gratuity' for exceptional service.

Comment: Absolutely +1 for this. I spent many years working server/bartender jobs in school and I can vouch for the fact that waitstaff are often overworked and underpaid considering the stress of the job (in a busy restaurant, anyways). Often there are things the guest may construe as bad service but were in fact out of the server's control. Tip at least 15% and *leave a constructive comment* instead of stiffing them, so they can at least pay their rent.

Comment: What if they hardly response to my requests, but very responsive at other tables? And if the restaurant is not at the peak hours?

Comment: Time for living minimum wages so wait staff has not to beg for money. Raise the price of the food and pay that to the staff.

Comment: +1 for the comparison to almost every other job, in which I get paid the same regardless of how well I do an individual task. Everyone has a bad day. It would be nice if we just started paying servers properly, but until then, tipping is a necessity.

Comment: @tuananh while that can be frustrating, there are any number of understandable reasons for such behavior. Maybe the waiter was forced to work a double shift last night and is exhausted or distracted. Maybe the management has instructed them to take special care of the other table for some reason. Maybe the other table are simply flagging them down in a more noticeable way.

Comment: I understand the instinct not to tip if you believe the waiter is acting with malice against you personally, but even if it might feel that way I would give them the benefit of the doubt and let them have their income.

Comment: @user29655 A server's reasons for not being 100% on their game is not the customer's fault nor problem. I, as a customer, should not pay a premium for terrible service.

Comment: @Ghost no one is going to stop you from leaving a stingy tip for whatever reason you see fit, and I doubt I can convince you not to do so. That said, in this case and others, I think it's better for one to do what is generous and kind even if it's not strictly their "fault or problem". And I would reiterate that from the server's perspective, a tip isn't a "premium", it's their income.

Comment: @ghost there are a lot of things you might think you should not or won't do, and you'd be correct. however, there's still value in *doing them anyway* just because that's how society works. it took me a long time to realize this, but i get it now. i always tip 20% and just don't worry about. i don't like it, but i've also stopped caring. that's life.

Comment: I wouldn't say 20% is the fixed level, but certainly something well above zero.

Comment: If wait staff are severely overworked, then they're serving more customers than they should be, and so need a smaller tip from each customer in order to get a decent income. So it's fine to give them that smaller tip in order to reflect the poor service that you get because they're overworked.

Comment: @MikeScott In every industry I can think of, this one excluded, *taking on more responsibility is something that’s supposed to get a promotion or raise **up front.*** If there are too many customers, the server is working harder, responsible for more things – and that should mean they’re seeing more recompense. So no, it is not “fine” for them to get the same income when they have to serve more people, do more work and take more responsibility. That’d be the same as telling a salesperson their quota has gone up, but since they’ll have to sell more, they’ll get less per to make it “balance.”

Comment: @KRyan If they're able to maintain their standards while taking on more work, then they will indeed get more recompense. It's only if they can't handle the extra work and their standards slip that their tips won't and shouldn't go up in line with the number of extra customers.

Comment: @MikeScott And again, that is how literally no other industry works. Someone who is promoted too far and cannot handle the new responsibilities may be demoted (though they usually aren’t), but *for as long as those responsibilities are part of their job description, they are compensated accordingly.*

Comment: @KRyan name an industry where you get a promotion _before_ working above your job description.

Comment: @Gusdor In theory, *you are never supposed to work above your job description.* Your boss wants you to take on more responsibilities, wants to add to your job description, *then he has to promote you **first**,* change your job so that the new job description includes new responsibilities. In practice, this sometimes happens and sometimes does not, but people who get additional responsibilities piled on them with no concomitant increase in job title and/or pay are frequently advised to take this up with management *on this very site* because that is not how things are supposed to work.

Comment: @KRyan if im a manager, i want to know an employee can get the job done before promoting them. Formal demotions are bad for everyone. Responsibility is not always forced. You can ask first! Sometimes an employee will take it themselves and surpass expectations. Then you promote them in the knowledge that they can handle it. That is how the real world works.

Comment: @Gusdor That is *sometimes* how the real world works. But other times, a manager *needs the work done*, and has to convince someone to take on additional responsibilities – by enticing them with a promotion. And on the flip side, some managers see that the employee is already doing the work, so why promote them? And that is exactly the sort of behavior that MikeScott is promoting as “fine” for how waitstaff are compensated.

Comment: "In a case where the waiter is simply inattentive". Inattentive IS poor service.  I've left 1 cent in cases where I've had to go chase down my waitress.  Their entire job is to take care of you, and forgetting you're there fails that miserably.   poor service deserves poor tips, always.

Answer (score 16):

I like to tip them the smallest value coin I have; that way they knew I didn't forget a tip. Then I talk to the manager or email feedback.

Comment: This does not improve service for you or for anyone else. It's the equivalent of throwing a tantrum, and has just as much effect.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Talking to the manager and/or emailing them feedback is not constructive to improve the service quality of a server? It's not my job to make them better at serving others.

Comment: Tipping with a penny or a nickel is not constructive to improve service quality. Talking to the manager may get you a free meal, which is usually what a low-tipper really wants.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham I may have misunderstood this, not having lived in the US, but I completely fail to see how a low tip is not constructive, if used in combination with a complaint to the manager. A waiter who gets consistently low tips and many complaints will either have to improve or get fired/quit due to low income.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham How should an unhappy customer then express their disapproval of the service they received?

Comment: Just like any other business, if they don't provide the service you want, don't go there. The idea that you can change the way a business operates by withholding income from one of the employees is misguided.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham You don't believe that a waiter who provides terrible service won't be incentivised to improve after receiving a string of poor tips?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham I think restaurants provide food and servers provide service. Like cdkMoose said, food price is in the menu and service is in the tip. Waiters/waitresses should provide at least adequate service in order to receive reasonable tip.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Is the waiter supposed to remember all the people they have served and account for their lack of presence over the course of the next few months? That seems very difficult. Not going back because of bad food is ok but bad service...no one will ever know.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you philosophically, but pragmatically. In my experience in restaurants, bad tipping is thought to be a personality defect, and not generally a legitimate "message". A common opinion is that a diner leaves a penny on the table as a personal insult to the server. As with anyone else, personal insults are rarely constructive. But aside from all that, is there any other business where you can consume the product (service), and then decide not to pay for it?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham The internet?

Comment: @DanielF Which particular part of the Internet?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham "I don't think x is that good, so I will pirate it".

Comment: @JeremyNottingham You can also consume something in the internet and then return it for a full refund. If returned in 14 days or less. So yes there are other businessses where you can consume and not pay because you are not satisfied.

Comment: If a consumer does not want to leave a tip, is there an option to go to the kitchen and get the food myself? No? Tipping is apparently a mandatory tax on walking through the door.

Answer (score 11):

In many locations, tips are not only for the waitstaff, but are actually shared with the busboys, the bartender, and sometimes other members of the staff - usually not the cooks, but even occasionally then.

They're also a significant fraction of their wages, most waiters earning a few dollars an hour "plus tips" rather than a full, normal wage.  When I worked in college at a local breakfast/diner place, low prices but high table turn, I usually pulled $10-$15 an hour in tips, and $3.15 an hour in wages (IL minimum wage at the time), for example, and gave 25% of that to the bartender and the busboys (15% and 10% if I recall).

Tipping zero or near-zero, especially if you're obviously not American, will accomplish nothing other than make them think you're a foreigner with no idea of our customs.

Instead, tip at the low end of your comfort zone - for me that's dead minimum 10%, most of the time 20% with average to good service - and leave a comment with the waiter or the manager, depending on what the problem was, if it was significant enough to justify doing so.  If the waiter was simply inattentive, letting him know may be actually helpful to him in the future.  If the waiter was rude or otherwise you aren't comfortable talking to him, letting the manager know is helpful; be aware that if you do it in person prior to paying, it sends a signal you expect some compensation, so often doing it after you've paid is better.

As a former waiter myself, I definitely would've appreciated being let know if I wasn't sufficiently attentive to a table - and most of the time I probably knew already.  I was fairly good at my job, usually receiving among the highest percentage in tips of the restaurants I worked at (after the first one), but I still had tables I made mistakes at, days I wasn't as on top of things, or otherwise had issues.  A quick:

> Hey, thanks for serving me today.  Don't worry about the iced tea I asked for.

is a pretty non-confrontational way of reminding the waiter he didn't do something you asked for.

Comment: How you are paid is not the customers concern.  That you share tips is also none of their concern.  You knew full well what the jib entailed and kept it anyway.  You get poor tips for poor service.  Don't like any of that, find another job.

Answer (score 6):

I've never received such poor service that the waitperson did not deserve a tip for their time.  Most cases where the server did the worst job, they were obviously in, or just out of, training and still slightly overwhelmed.

I typically use 15% as a starting point.  If it was on the extreme end of bad, I'll play fast and loose, maybe round to the nearest $1 and short them down to 14% or so.  When I worked in a restaurant (15 years ago), the hourly wage was $2.13 an hour (or thereabouts... within $.10).  Unless they are outright hostile to me (which has never happened), they deserve their 15%.

This is in the US.

Comment: +1 To add detail to the wage part, $2.13/hr is the current federal minimum wage for a tipped employee; *however,* the employer is required to make up the difference if the $2.13/hr plus tips comes to less than regular minimum wage, i.e. $7.25/hr.

Comment: @Daniel If that's the case then foreigners should not feel guilty at all for not tipping.

Comment: @curiousdannii that's not the way it works. It's not figured per-table, i.e. if I spend an hour serving your table, and you don't tip me, the employer has to pay me the difference.  Typically a server will make up the difference on some of their tables and go *over* minimum wage in total - so if you don't tip, you're still taking away from that person's wage.  Waiting on tables is not intended to be a minimum wage job.

Comment: @Jason Agreed except with your last point.  Unskilled entry-level service jobs are the perfect candidates for minimum wage.  The minimum wage is just far too low.

Comment: Waiting tables is not an unskilled entry-level service job.  That would be fast-food.

Comment: @curiousdannii What Jason said. Unless the server is unfortunate enough to be paid at $2.13/hr *and* receive under $5.12/hr in tips (including yours!), you are lowering the server's pay by not tipping.

Comment: @Daniel - "To add detail to the wage part... the employer is required to make up the difference ..." I believe you are correct about this rule, unfortunately it "Never" happens that way. The employer has no way of knowing how much an employee (server) has received in total tips. They only know what the server has reported as the amount of tips they received, but that amount may be over-reported or under-reported. They will not pay the amount to cover the difference based only on the server claiming their tips were not sufficient. Otherwise many servers might falsely claim this.

Comment: @Daniel "you are lowering the server's pay by not tipping". If I lower the tip due to poor service I'm not lowering the servers pay, they didn't earn higher pay by providing good service.  Tips are not entitlements, they are freely given based on the level of service.

Comment: @Andy - to be pedantic, you *are* lowering their pay whether or not they earned it. The point here is that some people think if they don't tip, the restaurant will step in, at least somewhat; but that's not the case 98% of the time. Your tip decides their pay.

Comment: @Daniel no, lower implies it should have been higher but wasn't.  That's not the case if it hasn't been earned.  There's no guarantee of a tip, so any tips they get are more than should be expected.

Comment: I see I should have said "you are lowering the server's pay by not tipping versus tipping". My point was that the restaurant will not tip the server when you don't. See curiousdannii's comment above. Also, I disagree that any tips they get are more than should be expected. Tips are a major part of a server's pay, so it's starkly dismissive to consider them optional.

Comment: @Andy "more than should be expected" if you don't want to pay for service, go to a grocery store and fix your own food. Servers work for tips. If you don't tip them, they served your table *for free*. Whatever other wages come into play for their employment are just a guarantee that they won't be completely at the whim of the customer - i.e. the government *requires* the employer to guarantee *at least* minimum wage, so they do so. When they are serving your table, their compensation is the tip that you give them.

Comment: @Jason Take your strawman and get lost.  I do tip, and if I get excellent service I tip very well; average service gets average tip.  But if I get poor service the server gets a poor tip or no tip.  And they STILL don't serve my table for free, they STILL get paid the minimum wage allowed by law.  If my drink sucks, I don't pay for it.  If my meal sucks, I don't pay for it.  Why should I pay for service that sucks?  When someone serves my table, their compensation is minimum wage + whatever tip they earn based on how good their service is.  Its not really hard to understand.

Comment: If you don't tip a server then they served your table for free, it's just that the service you got was subsidized by the other tables and, if they fail to cover minimum wage, the restaurant. There's a sizable gray area here where I don't know what really constitutes poor service to you. I've laid out my own view in my answer: outright hostility. If the server can't even get my food to me then I'll pay for my drinks and go, which absolves me of any financial responsibility for the meal or the service of that meal. If they bring me my food while I still want it, they deserve to be paid.

Answer (score 6):

The quality of the food is irrelevant to the tip.  The cook gets payed a full wage and does not receive any of the tip.  Therefore your only concern when deciding how much to tip should be on the service provided by the waiter or waitress.  DO NOT reward the service staff for the work of the kitchen.

Personally, if I get bad service then I tip about half of the average; so about 7.5%.  If I get good service, then I tip over the average (22.5%).

My wife's entire professional career has involved some form of tipping, so she often tips up to 50% and believe me this has not gone unnoticed.  We would often have people recognize us when we enter a place that we frequent regularly, and get amazing service because they know a large tip is coming.

Answer (score 6):

Tim Urban's wonderfully thorough piece [Everything You Don't Know About Tipping](http://waitbutwhy.com/2014/04/everything-dont-know-tipping.html) explains what tipping in the US is about.

Unless a server was actively hostile, rude and offensive to you, it's not right to deprive them of their income. That's just how it works in the US.

Furthermore, as is mentioned, if they get good tips, servers see it as a reflection of their good service, but if they get bad tips, they see it as a very poor reflection on the tipper. The tip on its own is therefore not an effective means of communicating your satisfaction (or lack thereof) with the service: tipping below 10% is depriving the server of their income (which they deserve even with what many might consider "subpar" service), but tipping above that is still in the range of what people might give for ordinary service, so your intentions are left unclear.

You can certainly tip on the lower end of the acceptable range (15%, or a bare minimum of 10% if service was *truly* bad), but keep in mind that this is meaningless unless you **communicate your dissatisfaction clearly using words**. Speaking to the manager is helpful for all concerned: the manager is aware of the problem, the server gets the opportunity to improve, and you have successfully communicate your dissatisfaction. In fact, you may even receive a gift certificate.

To answer the more direct question: Certainly **don't base your tip on the quality of the food**, but don't base it too strongly on the quality of service, either. It's just not that helpful for anyone. Consider it part of the price of the meal; don't spend the meal judging the server; and if at the end of the meal you have strong opinions about the quality of service, communicate that directly.

Comment: Interesting point in the link about tipping ratios of a country correlating with corruption in that country - that might help to explain the different attitudes to tipping amongst different nationalities, which seem to vary from "you should always tip" to "why would you pay someone extra for doing their job?". There are places where handing over extra cash is seen as unsavoury, and I've seen people refuse to take tips that were offered.

Answer (score 3):

While in the US, you should definitely tip. This should only be based on the service; you're tipping your waiter/waitress, NOT the cook. I generally use 20% as my starting point, if I don't feel that they did a good job I'll drop down to 15% (or further if need be). Likewise, I'll go up to 30% if I feel like the server really earned it. In almost all cases, this is their paycheck. They DO need to earn it, but if they do a great job, let them know.

If the service was seriously lacking AND the place wasn't obviously busy (we must take that into account!), I'll drop the tip to 10%. However, in this case it's also appropriate to leave a note with a 'tip' on how to improve. Keep it positive, constructive criticism, be nice.

I have used the penny tip before. But for something like that, the server has to pretty well straight out offend me. It's not something reserved for poor service.

Tipping aside, keep in mind that you CAN speak with the servers' manager, about their performance. I will stress with this statement, that if you have an amazing server, that's just as important to convey to the manager as well, so that they can be rewarded for being awesome.

Comment: Tips in the US are frequently pooled, with the waitstaff cutting dishwashers and sometimes other kitchen staff in, so you are not tipping just the waitstaff.

Answer (score 2):

In all but the most exceptional circumstances try to tip between 10-20% (even 10 is a bit low) however certain scenarios would definitely lean towards not following this standard, keep reading for my own personal example.

I went to a Chili's restaurant for dinner, it wasn't busy at all and we were seated immediately. Our server took our order and then we never saw her again, another server dropped off our food and no one ever came to ask how it was or check if we wanted anything else. Finally we ended up needing to walk up to the hostess to get and pay our bill; we made a point of not tipping at all.

Answer (score 0):

A feedback to the managerial staff of how the waiter/waitress served you will do it I believe. However it the food is great surely leaving a tip is something that can be consider, since in the kitchen there are some dedicating cook that are making everything they can to put a smile on your face when you're leaving the restaurant.

Comment: You tip for service not the quality of the food.

Answer (score 0):

Just for additional information and warning:

A lot of restaurants in New England and along the Canadian border will add an automatic 18% gratuity to your bill.  This means they've decided how much you're going to tip and put it on your bill.

They will always tell you that they're adding it, or forewarn you that it will be added... but only ever in small print.  A lot of people don't notice and tip twice.  Servers will never turn down two tips on the same bill.

Comment: From my experience, the auto 18%-tip thing usually only for parties of 6 or more, OR in unusually swanky restaurants. But I have only limited  experience dining in New England or along the Canadian border so maybe something peculiar is going on there.

Comment: I live in NE near the Canadian border, and the auto 18% is the same as it is anywhere else I've been in the USA, only done for parties 6-8 or more.